# Spring MVC Validator typeMismatch

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-validator

I have created Spring MVC project in Eclipse Juno. The Controller as shown:

```
@Controller
public class JftController {

    @Autowired
    JenisJftManager jenisJftManager;

    @Autowired
    JftManager jftManager;

    @Autowired
    JftValidator jftValidator;

    @InitBinder
    private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder){
        binder.setValidator(jftValidator);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/jft/view", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAll(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("jftList", jftManager.getAll());
        return "jftView";       
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/jft/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String formJft(Model model){
        Map<Integer, String> jenisJft = jenisJftManager.getAllJenisJftMap();            
        model.addAttribute("jft", new Jft());
        model.addAttribute("jenisJft", jenisJft);
        return "jftAdd";        
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/jft/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addJft(@Validated @ModelAttribute("jft") Jft jft, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){
        System.out.println("1");
        System.out.println("2");
        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            System.out.println("2.1");
            Map<Integer, String> jenisJft = jenisJftManager.getAllKelasMap();
            model.addAttribute("jenisJft", jenisJft);

            for (Object object : result.getAllErrors()) {
                if(object instanceof FieldError) {
                    FieldError fieldError = (FieldError) object;
                    System.out.println("FieldError = "+fieldError.getCode());
                }
                if(object instanceof ObjectError) {
                    ObjectError objectError = (ObjectError) object;
                    System.out.println("ObjectError = "+objectError.getCode());
                }
            }           
            return "jftAdd";
        } else {
            System.out.println("2.2");
            jftManager.add(jft);
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Jabatan Fungsional Berhasil ditambah!");
            return "redirect:/jft/view";
        }
    }   

}
```

The Form is as shown below:

```
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>            
    <title>Untitled</title>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value='/resources/css/main.css' />">    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value='/resources/css/font-awesome.min.css' />">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="<c:url value='/resources/images/favicon.png' />">
  </head>
  <body class="app sidebar-mini rtl">                         
    <form:form method="POST" class="form-horizontal" action="" modelAttribute="jft">        
    <div class="tile-body">              
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Nama Jabatan Fungsional</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <form:input path="name" class="form-control" cssErrorClass="form-control is-invalid" maxlength="60" />
          <form:errors path="name" class="form-control-feedback" />                    
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Kelas Jabatan</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">                                                                                                         
          <form:select path="jenis" items="${jenisJft}" class="form-control" />                                   
        </div>
      </div>          
    </div>
    <div class="tile-footer">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-3">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg fa-check-circle"></i>Tambah</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </form:form>            
  </body>
</html>
```

The Jft model is shown below:

```
public class Jft {
    public Integer id;
    public String name; 
    public JenisJft jenis;  

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }   

    public JenisJft getJenis() {
        return jenis;
    }

    public void setJenis(JenisJft jenis) {
        this.jenis = jenis;
    }   
}
```

And JftJenis model is shown below:

```
public class JenisJft {
    public Integer id;
    public String name;
    public Boolean isDeleted;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Boolean getIsDeleted() {
        return isDeleted;
    }

    public void setIsDeleted(Boolean isDeleted) {
        this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
    }

}
```

When I submit the form, bindingResult has error. Actually I know the cause. The problem is, Spring Validator try to match data type for Jft.jenis. The value return from html form is Integer, but Jft.jenis is not Integer but JenisJft. The output from Apache Tomcat is shown below:
[image]

I've google this but still did not found the answer. How to solve this? How can I map this Integer value from html to JenisJft?

Comment: return id of jenisJft and then create the jenisjft object using that id...and create a custom validator

Comment: After read java and spring documentation, there are two solutions: (1) change Jft.jenis to Integer; (2) create custom validator. CMIIW